# How to set all pixels of an OpenCV Mat to a specific value?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have an image of type `CV_8UC1`. How can I set all pixel values to a specific value?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

- **For grayscale image:**

  ```
  cv::Mat m(100, 100, CV_8UC1); //gray 
  m = Scalar(5);  //used only Scalar.val[0]
  ```

  or

  ```
  cv::Mat m(100, 100, CV_8UC1); //gray 
  m.setTo(Scalar(5));  //used only Scalar.val[0]
  ```

  or

  ```
  Mat mat = Mat(100, 100, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(5));
  ```
- **For colored image (e.g. 3 channels)**

  ```
  cv::Mat m(100, 100, CV_8UC3); //3-channel 
  m = Scalar(5, 10, 15);  //Scalar.val[0-2] used
  ```

  or

  ```
  cv::Mat m(100, 100, CV_8UC3); //3-channel 
  m.setTo(Scalar(5, 10, 15));  //Scalar.val[0-2] used
  ```

  or

  ```
  Mat mat = Mat(100, 100, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(5,10,15));
  ```

---

**P.S.**: Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23510571/2589776) if you further want to know how to set given channel of a `cv::Mat` to a given value efficiently without changing other channels.

Answer (score 10):

The assignment operator for `cv::Mat` has been implemented to allow assignment of a `cv::Scalar` like this:

```
// Create a greyscale image
cv::Mat mat(cv::Size(cols, rows), CV_8UC1);

// Set all pixel values to 123
mat = cv::Scalar::all(123);
```

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-operator) describes:

> Mat& Mat::operator=(const Scalar& s)
>
> s – Scalar assigned to each matrix element. The matrix size or type is not changed.

Comment: since Scalar(123) only initializes the *1st* element of the Scalar, you probably want  Scalar::all(123) , if the Mat has more than one channel.

Answer (score 5):

In another way you can use

[Mat::setTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-setto)

Like

```
      Mat src(480,640,CV_8UC1);
      src.setTo(123); //assign 123
```