# Why Scalar does not work?

Tags: c++, opencv, scalar

Following code results in build success, but no window. Without "m = Scalar(255,0,0);", it creates black window. Why including scalar does not work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Mat m = Mat::zeros(200,200,CV_8UC3);
    m = Scalar(255,0,0);  //without this, it creates window. 

    imshow("m", m);
    waitKey();

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set all pixels of an OpenCV Mat to a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816955/how-to-set-all-pixels-of-an-opencv-mat-to-a-specific-value)

Comment: This question would be better deleted as it does not bring anything helpfull for the community (given the issue was to clean & build). Consider that.

Answer (score 0):

It will not give you any compilation error as Mat and Scalar are basically array types of OpenCV.

This is a possible duplicate of [How to set all pixels of an OpenCV Mat to a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816955/how-to-set-all-pixels-of-an-opencv-mat-to-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 0):

Your code have to work!

take a look at the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow):

> C++: void imshow(const string& winname, InputArray mat)

and I can confirm you is working fine on my environment(opencv320, VisualStudio2017):
you need to clean the project and build again.

[image]